# How to create a folder in AWS S3 using AWS Lambda for a user authenticated by Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am trying to invoke a lambda function that creates AWS resources (S3 folder and DynamoDB Item) for authenticated users. Lambda function will be invoked from client side after the user is logged in through AWS Cognito.

Making an S3 putObject request from client-side works fine. However, if I make the same request from the invoked Lambda function, it fails.

```
Client --> S3 --> Works
Client --> Lambda --> S3 --> Does not work
```

Here is my Lambda function:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
id = str(context.identity.cognito_identity_id)
bucket.put_object(Key='cognito/users/{}/'.format(id))
```

I get the following error

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: 
Access Denied
```

Both Cognito Authenticated Role and Lambda Role is pointing to the same role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["lambda:InvokeFunction"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:function:CreateResources"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": ["cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/cognito/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:IDENTITY_POOL_ID"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole",
        "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does you Lambda execution role look like? Does it allow s3:PutObject?